# Which open source e-commerce solution for subscriptions?

Tags: open-source, e-commerce, subscription

We plan to build a new store for our web site. We want it to be able to handle subscriptions. As software editor, we will sell subscriptions for our support services and SaaS offers.

The solution must be able to manage renewal, invoices generation, in an international context (Europe with VAT, international without VAT).

We also must be able to integrate it with our provisioning system using APIs or by using a understandable database model.

Last thing, our web site is based on Drupal. We already made some tests with Ubercart which were not satisfactory.

Thank you for your hints !

Answer (score 0):

There are many `Open source` eCommerce platforms available. Among those `Magento` looks good to me. You might check out the options [here](http://incept09.hubpages.com/hub/The-Best-5-Free-Open-Source-E-Commerce-Platform). If you are really looking for something to integrate with `Drupal` then among few options [this is one](http://www.drupalecommerce.org/).